# m2e Failure to transfer junit

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, m2e

The following issue appear in the Markers view when importing my Maven pom files with m2eclispe:

> Failure to transfer junit:junit:jar:3.8.1 from (http://nexus.xyz.com/content/groups/public) was cached in the local repository, 
>   resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 
>   Original error: Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:jar:3.8.1 from/to central (http://xyz.com/content/groups/public): 
>   The operation was cancelled.    pom.xml /project    line 1  Maven Configuration Problem

Do I need to add a plugin exclusion filter for m2e to my pom?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Maven is configured to download any artifacts from your corporate Maven repository.  This is a common setup. Usually the corporate Maven repository acts as a proxy to the [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/), which contains most of the open source libraries like JUnit. But this doesn't seem to work in your setup. The attempt to download JUnit fails and your are getting this error.

Comment: I think its more of a m2eclipse issue. The project builds fine from the console (mvn clean install). Also we are using Junit 4 not 3.8.1 so I'm not sure where it is picking this up from.